# How to turn off Rack Attack in Gitlab CE Omnibus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am using Gitlab CE that I installed via the omnibus package, and I am using it exclusively for the API components.

I am having another application server access the API endpoints using cURL, therefore to Gitlab it looks like all of the requests are coming from the same IP address.

When I try to access the "protected paths" such as logging in or signing up a user the first 10 work, then Rack::Attack kicks in and throws 429 errors.

This is the path to the file for the configuration that I found:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/rack_attack.rb
```

This file has this line at the top:

```
#This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
#erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
#and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
```

When I try to edit this file directly it is reverted when I do the reconfigure.

I can't find anything in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file that would allow me to configure these settings. Does anyone know how I can do this? I would rather install Rack::Attack on my application server and just leave Gitlab open since my server is the only thing hitting it directly.

Answer (score 5):

It was broken until https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/791

If you have omnibus version with this merge request applied, then just add the following to gitlab.rb config:

```
gitlab_rails['rack_attack_git_basic_auth'] = {
   'enabled' => false,
}
```

Comment: You will likely have to reconfigure gitlab by running `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for this to take effect